# C-code to assembly

Tags: c, arrays, assembly, mips, pipeline

I was trying to convert C code to MIPS assembly. Here's a snippet. The problem is that i'm not too sure if i am going along the right track. I'm hoping, someone could help.

This was the original question:

```
void swap(int v[], int k, int j) { 
int temp; 
temp = v[k]; 
v[k] = v[j]; 
v[j] = temp; 
}
```

and this is how far i have got:

```
swap:
addi      $sp, $sp, -4
sw        $s0, 0($sp)
add       $s0, $zero, $zero
L1: add   $t1, $s0, $a1
lb        $t2, 0($t1)
add       $t3, $s0, $a0
sb        $t2, 0($t3)
beq       $t2, $zero, L2
addi      $s0, $s0, 1
j L1
L2:       lw $s0, 0($sp)
addi      $sp, $sp, 4
jr        $ra
```

Alright this is as far as i have got. Am i doing this right or am i completely lost it!?

Comment: I don't see a question. Please consult the help button in the top row to see how to ask questions on SO. For the problem at hand, producing assembler from C code, all compilers that I know of have a command line switch to produce that. E.g gcc has `-S`. What is your problem?

Comment: well you have a loop, the C code doesnt have a loop.  The arrays are of int which we can assume is 4 bytes or 32 bits.  so you need to multiply k by 4 or shift left 2, then add that to v and load that into temp.  then create a j times 4 offset that into v and store into v plus k times 4.  then put temp into v plus j times 4.   Is your code doing that?

Comment: It seems that the poster is trying to learn MIPS assembler and c-calling conventions.  Seems like a fair question to me.  But given how few people on here are MIPS experts, the suggestion of generating an asm file from the given c compiler is a good one.

Comment: That looks more like a translation/implementation of `strcpy` to me.... set `s0` to `0`, then copy byte for byte from address `a1+s0` to `a0+s0`, jump to `L2` if the value just written was `== 0`, otherwise jump back to `L1`.

Comment: That assembly code indeed looks like it has nothing to do with your C code. What's the story here?

Answer (score 3):

break it down and then implement it

v, k and j come in as registers we assume.

you need to build the address v+(k<<2) and v+(j<<2) You can use scratch registers, I assume you can trash the k and j incoming registers too since you wont need them anymore.

```
k = k << 2;
k = k + v
j = j << 2;
j = j + v
temp0 = load(k)
temp1 = load(j)
store(k) = temp1
store(j) = temp0
```

and you should be able to convert that to asm, can re-arrange some of the instructions and have it still work.

Edit, I will let you figure it out, but I didnt cheat and compile first.  But found that gcc produced the same basic sequence of instructions.  Two shifts, two adds two loads, then two stores.

Answer (score -2):

Here's a [free online tool](http://reliant.colab.duke.edu/c2mips/) that converts c code to assembly.

Here is the converted code:

```
    addiu   $sp,$sp,-24
$LCFI0:
    sw  $fp,20($sp)
$LCFI1:
    move    $fp,$sp
    movz    $31,$31,$0
$LCFI2:
    sw  $4,24($fp)
    sw  $5,28($fp)
    sw  $6,32($fp)
    lw  $2,28($fp)
    nop
    sll $2,$2,2
    lw  $3,24($fp)
    nop
    addu    $2,$3,$2
    lw  $2,0($2)
    nop
    sw  $2,8($fp)
    lw  $2,28($fp)
    nop
    sll $2,$2,2
    lw  $3,24($fp)
    nop
    addu    $2,$3,$2
    lw  $3,32($fp)
    nop
    sll $3,$3,2
    lw  $4,24($fp)
    nop
    addu    $3,$4,$3
    lw  $3,0($3)
    nop
    sw  $3,0($2)
    lw  $2,32($fp)
    nop
    sll $2,$2,2
    lw  $3,24($fp)
    nop
    addu    $2,$3,$2
    lw  $3,8($fp)
    nop
    sw  $3,0($2)
    move    $sp,$fp
    lw  $fp,20($sp)
    addiu   $sp,$sp,24
    j   $31
    nop
```

Comment: and unoptimized and much harder to interpret and/or code than do it by hand.

Comment: I've edited, didn't see the *mips* part just the assembly so I jumped on the answer thinking he wanted x86 asm.

Comment: @Siguza No, it's mips. Note the `lw` and `sw` instructions. And, the triple argument `addu` instructions, etc.

Comment: The originally linked tool does have MIPS as a target option though, as well as the option to add flags (`-O3`). [Doesn't look so bad then](https://godbolt.org/g/483MWC).

Comment: @CraigEstey I commented before the edit. ;) Yes, it's MIPS now. Still unoptimised though. :P

Comment: @Siguza I did after. Wires crossing ... :-). And, the autogenerated code is pretty sub-optimal as dwelch mentioned